# How to find list rows and columns index in Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to print row and column index in list.

I've used (loop below) this but Its one or the other..

```
a = [[0,0,1],
    [0,1,0],
    [1,0,0]]
def a():
x = 0
for sol in solutions:
    print(sol)
    for row in sol:
        print(row)
```

I am trying to print 
(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)

Index of 1s 
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to generate indices for a list:

```
for row, sublist in enumerate(a):
    for column, item in enumerate(sublist):
        if item:
            print((row, column))
```

This outputs:

```
(0, 2)
(1, 1)
(2, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like numpy you can turn it into a numpy array and use [argwhere()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html)

```
import numpy as np
a = [[0,0,1],
    [0,1,0],
    [1,0,0]]

a = np.array(a)
answer = np.argwhere(a==1)
```

This will output:

```
[[0 2]
 [1 1]
 [2 0]]
```